# importing basemap in r

Tags: r, spatial

I'm working with ggplot2 to complete some mapping in R. However, I need to use the United Nations "Carto Tile" as my basemap - available here: https://www.un.org/geospatial/mapsgeo/webservices

Any ideas on how to import this map or if there is an R package for it?

I'm currently using the basemap in the "maps" package as an alternative.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using ggmap? I don't think that lets you use custom basemaps, but you could look at how they implement the code. Also your link isn't loading anything for me. Carto has several basemaps it uses, do you mean any of these? https://carto.com/help/building-maps/basemap-list/

Answer (score 0):

I also use this basemap because the borders are compliant with UN policies on maps. Here is the mapbox gl.js library: https://github.com/UN-Geospatial/cartotile-plain-design.

You should be able to extract the data as an .geojson file which you can use as a basemap.